# create backend API for Mobile Apps using wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i have the latest installation of wordpress.
what i want to do is this:

Suppose i have a site at www.mysite.com and it is running wordpress
now i want to create a page called userAuth.php so the url will be www.mysite.com/myapp/userAuth.php when this page is open the user is presented with a login form.

On successful authentication of the use he is presented with another form userData.php where he has fields such name,sname,no etc where he can enter the details and save them.

Then when on my mobile app i get the data form www.mysite.com/myapp/servData.php i will get the data the user has entered.

i know how to code the above mentioned interface in PHP but i was wondering is there a plugin or some other hack in WordPress that i can use for my api needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSON-API` WordPress plugin for creating the web-services that can be used for fetching the data from Wordpress by mobile app.

And the plugin will provide the webservice url something like that :

`www.mysite.com/api/servicename`

Plugin link : https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

Hope it helps you some extent.